# Minify Javascript using JSMin.php

Tags: php, javascript, performance, zend-framework, minify

I have a website with JSMin minification on server side. The problem is that my server became slow after implementing the JSMin

This happens because there are urls that import some other specific files and these files are added to the minified one.

Now I would like to know if I should always load these specific scripts into one big minified file or if I should forget this approach and import the scripts as separated files.

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.x with BundlePhu + JSMin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution, which I have implemented in many projects, is to split all your javascript into finite files of maximum 200kb. I always split the JS into two (or rarerly three) files. The first one is libraries (jquery, zepto, swfobject, bootup...) and "user code" (my own $().clicks...).

I have a `.htaccess` inside my `/js` folder which rewrites all `scripts.js?version=45445` to `compiler.php`. The compiler script then verifies the version number, checks for cached compiled script and returns it. If not found, compiles on the fly, places in cache and returns it. That way the js gets compiled say every hour, and it's always minified.

I'm glad you do care about the 1kb you save with compression.

Here's a sample code:

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^scripts_(\d+).js(.*)$ __compress_js.php?_v=$1 [L]
```

And then something like this, in php

```
<?php
// __compress_js.php
ob_start();
include 'config.php';
$cache = FileCache::getInstance();
$cache->setPath(CACHE_PATH);

$cache_key = '_compressed_' . VERSION . '.js';

if ( ! $cache->check($cache_key, 3600)){
    $js = JSMin... // array of files
    $cache->write($cache_key, $js);
}
Header::js();
echo $cache->read($cache_key, 3600);
```

The above solution slows down only the FIRST hit. Everyone else is served a cached javascript.

Comment: Even better would be using .htaccess to rewrite to existing files, that are on the first run created by the php script.

Answer (score 2):

It will be better for the clientside performance if you compact all the scripts into one file. One of the slowest things a browser has to do is to make a new http connection to download a new file. By putting all you JavaScript into one minified file you can significantly improve performance over having a bunch of seperate minified scripts.

On the other hand, doing that extra processing is going to hurt your server performance. It's up to you whether you want to trade off server performance for client performance. Bear in mind however that there is research that shows that [clientside slowdowns of as little as 100ms can affect your site's conversion rate](http://alistapart.com/article/improving-ux-through-front-end-performance).